# Print default value if index is not in awk array

Tags: awk, associative-array

```
$ cat file1 #It contains ID:Name   
5:John  
4:Michel

$ cat file2 #It contains ID  
5  
4  
3
```

I want to Replace the IDs in file2 with Names from file1, output required

```
John  
Michel  
NO MATCH FOUND
```

I need to expand the below code to reult NO MATCH FOUND text.

```
awk -F":" 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {print a[$1]}' file1 file2
```

My current result:

```
John  
Michel  
        << empty line
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a ternary operator for this: `print ($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NO MATCH FOUND"`. That is, if `$1` is in the array, print it; otherwise, print the text "NO MATCH FOUND".

All together:

```
$ awk -F":" 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} {print ($1 in a)?a[$1]:"NO MATCH FOUND"}' f1 f2
John
Michel
NO MATCH FOUND
```

Comment: you can remove the `in` check and use `print a[$1]?a[$1]:"NO MATCH FOUND"` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can test whether the index occurs in the array:

```
$ awk -F":" 'NR==FNR {a[$1]=$2;next} $1 in a {print a[$1]; next} {print "NOT FOUND"}' file1 file2
John
Michel
NOT FOUND
```

Answer (score 0):

if file2 has only digit (no space at the end)

```
awk -F ':' '$1 in A {print A[$1];next}{if($2~/^$/) print "NOT FOUND";else A[$1]=$2}' file1
```

if not

```
awk -F '[:[:blank:]]' '$1 in A {print A[$1];next}{if($2~/^$/) print "NOT FOUND";else A[$1]=$2}' file1 file2
```